# how to extract string from text using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting

i have the following text

A shell script is a (script) written for "the shell", or command line interpreter, of an operating system. The shell is [often] considered a "simple" domain-specific programming language.

i need to print the strings surrounded by double quotes only using script?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Without knowing what OS/tools you have available, this would be impossible to answer.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick dah man i've finish uni years ago ...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek OS is Fedora 15 with bash shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as quoted strings dont span lines and don't contain quoted or escaped quotes:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while m!"([^"]+)"!g' maxwell.txt
the shell
simple

$ cat maxwell.txt
i have the following text

A shell script is a (script) written for "the shell", or command line interprete
r, of an operating system. The shell is [often] considered a "simple" domain-spe
cific programming language.

i need to print the strings surrounded by double quotes only using script?

Thanks!
$
```